# Difference between String created by String, StringBuilder and StringBuffer

Tags: java, string

I was checking how java creates references for Strings

I wrote the below code

```
        String s = new String("Tushar");
        String s1 = new String("Tushar");

        System.out.println("String HashCode");

        System.out.println(s.hashCode());
        System.out.println(s1.hashCode());

        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("Tushar");
        StringBuffer stringBuffer1 = new StringBuffer("Tushar");

        System.out.println("StringBuffer HashCode");

        System.out.println(stringBuffer.hashCode());
        System.out.println(stringBuffer1.hashCode());

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("Tushar");
        StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder("Tushar");

        System.out.println("StringBuilder HashCode");

        System.out.println(stringBuilder.hashCode());
        System.out.println(stringBuilder1.hashCode());
```

The output was as follows

```
String HashCode
-1778537625
-1778537625
StringBuffer HashCode
715152323
99120402
StringBuilder HashCode
1616769989
942619632
```

Why the hashcodes of StringBuilders and StringBuffers don't match.

Are these just memory locations to which they are allocated or the hash code is created based upon the string passed?

**EDIT:**

*Understanding :* The hashcode of the value remains same irrespective of the way it is created.

Confusion : What are the values printed (hash of instance variable, what does is mean?).

Comment: Print the hashCode from the `toString()` of your StringBuffer and StringBuilder!

Comment: and no, they are not memory locations.

Comment: e.g., `System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString().hashCode());`

Comment: ``Returns a hash code value for the object. This method is supported for the benefit of hash tables such as those provided by HashMap.`` it's not an memory location. it's an reference to the object

Comment: If you actually look at the addresses what you will probably find is that your strings point to the same memory address while all the others (even after the .toString() point to others.  This means that s == s1, but stringBuffer.toString() is probably != stringBuffer1.toString()

Comment: Part of the confusion is probably that when you print a "StringBuilder" or buffer it LOOKS like the string but this is only because Java often does a magic ".toString()" on objects that it feels it needs to.  If calling toString().hashCode() doesn't feel right, try this (It will match the string's hash code):  ("" + stringBuilder).hashCode()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every class can choose to calculate the hash code in it's own way. Hash codes don't have meaning, and very simple rules (abbreviated):

- Objects where `equals()` return true **must** return same hash code.
- Objects where `equals()` return false *should* return different hash code, to the best ability of the class, to ensure better performance of hash tables such as `HashMap` and `HashSet`.

Since a `String` with value `"ABC"` and a `StringBuilder` with value `"ABC"` are not *equal*, there is no requirement that they return the same hash code.

If you extract a `String` value from the `StringBuilder`, then *that* string value must have same hash code as another string of the same value, and it will, so the following two expression will return the same value:

```
new String("ABC").hashCode()
new StringBuilder("AB").append("C").toString().hashCode()
```

As a side note: Neither `StringBuilder` nor `StringBuffer` implements `equals()` and `hashCode()`, so their equality is based on *identity*, not value. Two `StringBuilder` objects with same value will still not be "equal", and will therefore (most likely) not have same hash code.

Comment: **equality is based on identity** are your referring to references here? 
**Two StringBuilder objects with same value will still not be "equal"**. As there references are different.
Is this what you want to convey?

Comment: @TusharBanne Yes, I use the word "identity" here to mean "same object reference value", in the same way it is used by [`System.identityHashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-), [`IdentityHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html), [`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--), ...

Answer (score 1):

The lines `stringBuilder.hashCode()` and `stringBuffer.hashCode()` gets you the hash of the instances of the stringBuilder and stringBuffer hence the difference.

Since the String are immutable (see my edit), getting the hash of the string of the `stringBuilder` and `stringBuffer` will be the same.

So:

```
System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString().hashCode());     
System.out.println(stringBuffer1.toString().hashCode());

System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString().hashCode());
System.out.println(stringBuilder1.toString().hashCode());
```

all will return the same hash

edit:
Note also, that the computing of the hash of the string is:

```
s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

So, even that there is only one copy of the string "abc" in memory, the hash of the same string return the same value at each run.

Comment: The hashcodes of the values are same. The question that arises is what are the values printed.(hash of the instances of the stringBuilder and stringBuffer) didn't understand this part.

Comment: StringBuilder and StringBuffer are anot immutable classes, so the contract says that two distinct object can return different hashcode. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Comment: Immutability has *nothing* to do with hash code equality!!

Comment: `stringBuilder.hashCode()` will not return same hash code as the other three.